I'm using React-Router-Dom for page routes. I need to separate admin routes from public ones. Can you suggest a Solution?
I am using React-Router-Dom for page routes. I need to separate admin routes from public ones.Can anyone tell me how do i do it.
App.js
import { createBrowserRouter,RouterProvider } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "./Pages/home";
import Contact from './Pages/contact';
import AboutPage from "./Pages/About";
import RootLayout from "./Pages/Root";
import ErrorPage from "./Pages/error";
import ProductPage from "./Pages/Product";
import ProductDetails from "./Pages/ProductDetails";

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
      path: '/',
      elements: <RootLayout />,
      errorElement: <ErrorPage />,
      children: [
        {path:'/', element:<HomePage />},
          { path: 'contact', element: <Contact /> },
          { path: 'about', element: <AboutPage /> },
          { path: 'product', element: <ProductPage /> },
          { path: 'product/:productId', element: <ProductDetails /> },
      ],
  },
]);

function App() {
  return (
  <RouterProvider router={router} />
  );
}

export default App;

I want admin Routes that are only accessible to admins only.

You can also find a working example for protected routes here

Here is an example
App.js
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Dashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import Login from './components/Login';

const App = () => {
  const isAuthenticated = true; //state determined from actual authentication logic

  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        <PrivateRoute
          path="/dashboard"
          component={Dashboard}
          isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated}
        />
        <Route
          path="/login"
          render={() =>
            isAuthenticated ? <Redirect to="/dashboard" /> : <Login />
          }
        />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;

PrivateRoute.js
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuthenticated ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;

Reference article : https://coderomeos.org/create-private-authenticated-routes-in-react
